# Show that the $GL(n,\mathbb R)/P_k$ is isomorphic to the $GL(n,\mathbb R)$-set grassmannian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions, grassmannian, general-linear-group

Let $r<n$ be two positive integers and $G=GL(n,\mathbb{R}).$ If $Gr(k,\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the set of all $k$-subspaces, then show that the $G$-sets $Gr(k,\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $G/P_k$ is isomorphic, given $P_k$ is the subgroup formed by all blockwise triangular matrices in the form $\begin{array}{l}\quad\left(\begin{array}{ll}A & B \\ 0 & D\end{array}\right) \\ \text { where } A \in G L(k, \mathbb{R}), D \in G L(n-k, \mathbb{R}), \text { and } B \in M_{k, n-k}(\mathbb{R})\end{array}$.

Should I make a homomorphism such that $P_k$ is the kernel of it, then use the 1st isomorphism theorem to prove it? Or should I find an isomorphism from these two $G$-sets directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $P_k$ is not normal and the Grassmannian is not a group. Instead, argue that $GL(n)$ acts transitively on $Gr(k)$ with stabilizer of one point $X\in Gr(k)$ (which one?) equal to $P_k$. Then construct a continuous bijection $GL(n)/P_k\to Gr(k)$, $g\mapsto gX$, $g\in GL(n)$. Then argue that the inverse is also continuous.

Comment: Should X be the trivial subspace ?

Comment: @Tifsir: Not at all, the stabilizer o $\{0\}$ is the entire $GL(n)$. Try to work out the case $n=2$ first.

Comment: @MoisheKohan It will the subspace of dimension k spanned by the standard basis.

Comment: @mulaan_20: Good job! (I think, OP also managed to figure this out by now.)

Comment: @MoisheKohan this question got recommended to me so i thought it was new . My post was similar to this. But I don't understand how to show that this map is continuous bijection? could you show it for simpler case like $n$=2 ?

Comment: @mulaan_20: Which part do you have trouble with: Continuous or bijection? What did you try?

Comment: @MoisheKohan well after finding the point , i constructed a map that takes the left cosets to Grassmannian space but it wasn't  well defined map. I tried after this, to construct a map from $g$-> $g$$X$ as you have mentioned ( its ofcourse bijective) but the continuous part is something i wasn't able to show .

Comment: @mulaan_20 do you see how to check continuity of the map from $Gl(n)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129217/discussion-between-mulaan-20-and-moishe-kohan).